# Call a method after user Login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I was wondering if there is away to call a function after the user login.

Here is the code I want to call:

```
$point = $this->container->get('process_points');
$point->ProcessPoints(1 , $this->container);
```

Comment: GitHub is currently down so I can't provide a full answer, but the way to do this is to override the FOSUserBundle controller in charge of the login.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can find the events FOSUserBundle fires in the [FOSUserEvents class](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php). More specifically, this is the one you are looking for:

```
/**
 * The SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN event occurs when the user is logged in programmatically.
 *
 * This event allows you to access the response which will be sent.
 * The event listener method receives a FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent instance.
 */
const SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN = 'fos_user.security.implicit_login';
```

The documentation for hooking into those events can be found on the [Hooking into the controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html) doc page. In your case, you will need to implement something like this:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN => 'onLogin',
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onLogin',
        );
    }

    public function onLogin($event)
    {
        // FYI
        // if ($event instanceof UserEvent) {
        //    $user = $event->getUser();
        // }
        // if ($event instanceof InteractiveLoginEvent) {
        //    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        // }

        $point = $this->container->get('process_points');
        $point->ProcessPoints(1 , $this->container);
    }
}
```

You should then define the listener as a service and inject the container. Alternatively, you could inject just the service you need instead of the whole container.

```
services:
    acme_user.login:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
        arguments: [@container]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

There is also another method which involves [overriding the controller](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.rst), but as noted in the documentation, you have to duplicate their code so it's not exactly clean and bound to break if (or rather, when) FOSUserBundle is changed.

Comment: thanks , really thanks ... i wouldn't have figured this out alone !

Comment: And is there any way to listen for "automatic login" ? Instead of listening only when user click on login. Example: User log in (with remember me) and next time when he will visit the page he will be logged in already but I would like to listen for this. I know I could listen for controller and check if the user exists from security context but I would like to listen for something from "security" part of symfony.

Comment: No because there is no actual login happening since it's simply using a cookie to authenticate the user.

Comment: No, after reading the source code, *implicit* login stands for logining in after registration completion, registration confirmation and reset completion. Not about explicit login... so, I am sorry, but your answer is factually wrong ([proof](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/92d5624f2a29e74d8fd9d2a94d7ed7998a8c2809/EventListener/AuthenticationListener.php)).

Comment: This event is fired by the listener I just given (click the "proof" link). Look closer at the class, it itself **listens for the registration and reset events** to then and only here fire the `SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN` event... it is never fired when explicitly loggining-in.

Comment: I'm currently looking for a working solution, and will edit your post, so as this is a quite old answer, don't bother in coming back to your mind's history :-).

Comment: I haven't touched Symfony in a long while, but if what you're saying is true, then why does [LastLoginListener.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/27663a642e551265653b54c4631f25fc4eca94a0/EventListener/LastLoginListener.php) listen for `FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN`? In your case, `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` might be worth looking at.

Comment: This listener is aware of `SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN` because we should consider an implicit login as a login despite everything. And you're right, `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` is the way to go (even if I have my own troubles here because this event is fired whatever the provider).

Comment: injecting the container is bad. Instead the `process_points` service should be injected.

Comment: @DanieleD "Alternatively, you could inject just the service you need instead of the whole container."

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau injecting the container should not really be an option in this case. it gives no benefits to the example. This is a question and your answer is one of the top results when researching on how to add a login listener for fos user. The main target of this question will be rather new symfony developers and they will see a service with an unnecessarily injected container.

Comment: @DanieleD You are entirely correct, unfortunately I haven't worked with Symfony2 in years. You are free to edit the code to only inject what is needed.

Comment: Perfect solution, but Symfony 2.8 I used "arguments: [@service_container"]. You can list all registered services by using command: php app/console container:debug. Hope this will help ;-)