# Override the login Controller in FOSUserBundle (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm currently migrating from a WordPress to a Symfony2 website.

I imported all my WP user on Symfony2 but now I'm looking for a way to make additional checks when the user tries to log in (typically check if the user was imported from WP and check his old password).

**What's the best way to add some checks on the User authentication ?** (login_check on fosuserbundle).

I simply try to override the SecurityController, but it doesn't work as the login doesn't seem to be made here.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**: I need to add my check during the login process, not after. During the login, if the user comes from WordPress, I want to check if the password he provides is the same as his old WordPress password (that is stored in the DB too).

Comment: Have a look for: class AuthenticationSuccessListener
{
    /**
     * @param AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccessResponse(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event)

Comment: or even better check out: http://www.webtipblog.com/create-authentication-listener-symfony-2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a method after user Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055721/call-a-method-after-user-login)

Comment: I would not override the controller but create an event listener for the ``fos_user.security.implicit_login`` event. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055721/call-a-method-after-user-login

Comment: Do you already know that *the user was imported from WP*? Did you stored this as a property or something else linked to the User?

Comment: Yes, I have a flag on the database to know is it was a WordPress user. In fact I need to make my check during the login, not after (onAuthenticationSuccess). Because, if the User was imported from FaceBook (I have a flag in database), then I will check if the password is the same as the old WordPress password and so, I'll set the password with the Symfony2 encoder and login the user.

Answer (score 2):

I finaly found a solution, but not sure it's the best way to do the stuff.

I added a listener when the login failed and check if it's a user from WordPress.

Now I'm looking for a solution to handle the "remember me" checkbox because the user is a authenticate programmatically. Here is the code :

```
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    $username = $request->request->get('_username');
    $password = $request->request->get('_password');

    $user = $this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneByUsername($username);

    if ($user instanceof User && $user->getFromWordpress() == true) {

        //The class use by WordPress to check / encode passwords
        $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);    

        //User provide the right password
        if ($hasher->CheckPassword($password, $user->getWordpressPassword())){

            //Programmatically authenticate the user
            $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), "main", $user->getRoles());
            $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
            $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
            $this->eventDispacher->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

            //Set the password with the Symfony2 encoder
            $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());
            $user->setPassword($password);
            $user->setFromWordpress(false);
            $this->doctrine->getManager()->persist($user);
            $this->doctrine->getManager()->flush();

            //Finnaly send login ok response
            return $this->onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
        }
    }   

    //Login failed code ...
    //.....
}
```